# How to replace a comma delimiter in string in csv file Unix - MAC OS

Tags: macos, csv, unix, awk, delimiter

I have a CSV file with a comma delimiter and need to remove this delimiter in string to manipulate the data.

The file is like :
**Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4**
100, 08 sciences, **"xx, yy, ww"**, US
110, 06 culture, **"abc, ww"**, US
115, 05 geology, **"geology"**, CA

I need to scan the string to replace the delimiter but don't know how to proceed.
I've tried sed 's/"*,*"/" "/g' (using Mac OS 10.10)

So when I'm trying to keep some column I can't reach the expected result :
cut -d , -f 2,3 myfile.csv > newfile.csv

I got :
08 sciences, "xx
06 culture, "abc
05 geology, "geology"

Instead of
08 sciences, "xx, yy, ww"
06 culture, "abc, ww"
05 geology, "geology"

Any help please ?

Comment: Is the troublesome field always known - I mean, can you say at the start it is field 3 this time? Is there just one troublesome field, or can there be two fields in double quotes on one line? Consider adding `awk` to your tags and you'll get an answer faster...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642102/how-to-make-awk-ignore-the-field-delimiter-inside-double-quotes might help

Comment: @Mark Setchell  To answer your question yes the problem is only on field 3 where there is text.

Comment: @Sundeep  Thanks, I gonna take a look

Answer (score 0):

When you want 2nd and third column, use

```
sed 's/[^,]*,//;s/,[^,]*//' inputfile
# or
sed 's/[^,]*,\(.*\),.*/\1/' inputfile
# or removing space before col3
sed 's/[^,]*, *\(.*\),.*/\1/' inputfile
```

Comment: I tried your script but the first column has been squeezed. I don't know why. Thus the delimiter is still in the string. Does your script just make a scan to read the entire string as a column from first quote until next ?

Comment: Perhaps you have `\r` in your file. You can look for `^M` with `cat -v inputfile` and remove them with `sed 's/\r//' inputfile` (option -i or redirect to other file).

Comment: I already did that but couldn't remove the CR. I guess it's because of macos. Gonna try on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your third column would consist of `" "`

```
$ awk -F"," -v OFS="," '{match($0,/\".*\"/,a); print $2 OFS a[0]}' file
 08 sciences,"xx, yy, ww"
 06 culture,"abc, ww"
 05 geology,"geology"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to replace commas with spaces in the field inside double quotes.

If so, use `awk` and tell it that the fields are separated by double quotes, and that you want to replace commas with spaces in field 2, like this:

```
awk -F'"' '{gsub(/,/," ",$2)}1' OFS='"' yourFile
```

**Sample Output**

```
100, 08 sciences, "xx  yy  ww", US
110, 06 culture, "abc  ww", US
115, 05 geology, "geology", CA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR>1{gsub(/^.....|....$/,"");print}' file

08 sciences, "xx, yy, ww"
06 culture, "abc, ww"
05 geology, "geology"
```