# Add missing columns to CSV file?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, command

## Starting Question

I have a CSV file which is formed this way (`variable.csv`)

```
E,F,G,H,I,J
a1,
,b2,b3
c1,,,c4,c5,c6
```

As you can see, the first and second columns do not have all the commas needed. Here's what I want:

```
E,F,G,H,I,J
a1,,,,,
,b2,b3,,,
c1,,,c4,c5,c6
```

With this, now every row has the right number of columns. In other words, I'm looking for a unix command which smartly **appends the correct number of commas to the end of each row** to make the row have the number of columns that we expect, based off the header.

Here's what I tried, based off of some searching:
`awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NF=6' variable.csv`. This works in the above case, BUT...

### Final Question

...Can we have this command work if the column data contains commas itself, or even new line characters? e.g.

```
E,F,G,H,I,J
"a1\n",
,b2,"b3,3"
c1,,,c4,c5,c6
```

to

```
E,F,G,H,I,J
"a1\n",,,,,
,b2,"b3,3",,,
c1,,,c4,c5,c6
```

(Apologies if this example's formatting is malformed due to the way the newline is represented.

Comment: Your command seems to work for your example. `NF=6` is an assignment, returning true, and then prints with additional commas. Are there any rows it doesn't work?

Comment: @thanasisp yes, it seems to have been a machine-specific issue. In addition I realize the core of my question is missing a critical component, so I've updated the main question to add that.

Comment: `awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' -v OFS=, 'NF=6' variable.csv` will work, ignoring commas inside quoted fileds. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642102/how-to-make-awk-ignore-the-field-delimiter-inside-double-quotes

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

```sh
python3 -c 'import fileinput,sys,csv;b=list(csv.reader(fileinput.input()));w=max(len(i)for i in b);print("\n".join([",".join(i+[""]*(w-len(i)))for i in b]))' variable.csv
```

The python script may be long, but this is to ensure that all cases are handled. To break it down:

```py
import fileinput,csv
b=list(csv.reader(fileinput.input()))                       # create a reader obj
w=max(len(i)for i in b)                                     # how many fields?
print("\n".join([",".join(i+[""]*(w-len(i)))for i in b]))   # output
```

BTW, in your starting problem

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NF<6{$6=""}1' variable.csv
```

should work. (I think it's implementation or version related. Your code works on GNU awk but not on Mac version.)