# Command to remove all but select columns for each file in unix directory

Tags: bash, unix

I have a directory with many files in it and want to edit each file to only contain a select few columns.

I have the following code which will only print the first column

```
for i in /directory_path/*.txt; do awk -F "\t" '{ print $1 }' "$i"; done
```

but if I try to edit each file by adding >'$I' as below then I lose all the information in my files

```
for i in /directory_path/*.txt; do awk -F "\t" '{ print $1 }' "$i" > "$i"; done
```

However I want to be able to remove all but a select few columns in each file for example 1 and 3.

Comment: Try `cut -f1 /directory_path/*.txt > output`

Comment: but wouldn't ```> output ``` then create a new file which I don't want

Comment: I want to edit the originals eg say I had 10 files with 5 columns. I want a solution where I still have 10 file but with only the first column

Comment: ok so no appending. Use `sed -E -i.bak 's/^([^[:blank:]]+).*/\1/' /directory_path/*.txt`

Comment: "Append" means to add on to the end. You appear to be trying to *remove* all but the first column from each file.

Comment: Yes sorry that is correct @chepner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given:

```
cat file
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

You can do in place editing with sed:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/^([^[:space:]]*).*/\1/' file 

cat file
1
4
```

If you want freedom to work with multiple columns and have in place editing, use GNU awk that also supports in place editing:

```
gawk -i inplace '{print $1, $3}' file

cat file 
1 3
4 6
```

If you only have POSIX awk or wanted to use `cut` you generally do this:

1. Modify the file with awk, cut, sed, etc
2. Redirect the output to a temp file
3. Rename the temp file back to the original file name.

Like so:

```
awk '{print $1, $3}' file >tmp_file; mv tmp_file file
```

Or with `cut`:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1,3 file >tmp_file; mv tmp_file file
```

To do a loop on files in a directory, you would do:

```
for fn in /directory_path/*.txt; do
    awk -F '\t' '{ print $1 }' "$fn" >tmp_file 
    mv tmp_file "$fn"
done
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm not experienced with sed command, how would I keep say 1 and 3

Comment: Keep 1 and 3 and then what with 4,5,6?

Comment: well in your example you have kept 1, how would I also keep column 3 in the same command

Comment: when I use the gawk command I get a rather long list of what the GAWK does but doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: I see how creating a temp and then renaming can be done, not sure how I could apply this to every file in my directory however

Comment: See example. You only need to be using one tmp file for a group of files since it is overwritten every time

Comment: And if you want to have a backup of each file, that is easily done as well. 1) add the extension to the file name in the loop 2) copy the original file to the backup; 3) redirect the output of awk to the tmp file; 4) mv tmp file to original.

Comment: Bit of a weird one. When I use ```awk -F "\t" 'NF != 7' file ``` to check how many columns are in my file they all print out. Whereas ```awk -F "\t" 'NF != 1' file ``` prints nothing out meaning the file thinks it has one column. My file which originally had something like 15 columns and now has 7 prints thinks it only has 1 column, any ideas?

Comment: Is the file truly separated by tabs or spaces? Try NOT setting `-F` so that awk splits on any whitespace.

Comment: yes it is, if I remove the '\t' then files are wiped blank

Comment: Ask a new question and post example data

Comment: I've used cut instead of print and this has worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little more to @dawg's perfectly well working answer according to my use case.

I was dealing with CSVs, and standard CSV can have `,` in some values as long as it's in double quotes like for example, the below-mentioned row will be a valid CSV row.

```
col1,col2,col2

1,abc,"abc, inc"
```

But the command above was treating the `,` between the double quotes as delimiter too.
Also, the output file delimiter wasn't specified in the command.
These are the modifications I had to make for it handle the above two problems:

```
for fn in /home/ubuntu/dir/*.csv; do
    awk -F ',' '{ FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; OFS=","; print $1,$2 }' "$fn" >tmp_file 
    mv tmp_file "$fn"
done
```

The `OSF` delimiter will be the diameter of the output/result file.
The `FPAT` handles the case of `,` between quotation mark. 
The regex and the information for that is mentioned ins `awk`'s official [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) in section `4.7 Defining Fields by Content`.

I was led to that solution through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29650812/10190191).