Fill column with longest value for each repeated element
I have the following csv file with repeated values in column1.
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,HEADER4
ap3,799,226:::5731,address 1
afk,731,+636:::773:992,address 2
ppd,411,8542,address 6
ap3,799,226,address 1:::address 9
ap3,799,474:::226:::5731,address 1
ppd,411,774:::+8825-22,address 6

For each repeated value in column1, I'd like to make equal the values of column 3 and column 4 in order to keep the value with longest length.
My current output is far away from what I'm looking for. Don't now how to follow.
$ awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '
    FNR==1 { print; next } {
    a[$0]=length($3)
}
END {
    for (i in a)
    print i,a[i]
}' input.csv
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,HEADER4
,14,731,+636:::773:992,address 2
,16,799,474:::226:::5731,address 1
,10,799,226:::5731,address 1
,33,799,226,address 1:::address 9
,4d,411,8542,address 6
,14,411,774:::+8825-22,address 6

Below the input (to the left) and the output (to the right) I'm looking for.


awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    NR>FNR {
        if (FNR>1) { $3=f3[$1]; $4=f4[$1] }
        print
        next
    }
    FNR>1 {
        if ( length($3)>length(f3[$1]) ) f3[$1]=$3
        if ( length($4)>length(f4[$1]) ) f4[$1]=$4
    }
' input.csv input.csv

Read the file twice.
The second time, perform substitutions and print.
The first time, save the longest values.

If multiple values have the longest length, the first seen will be chosen.

Thanks so much, it works pretty fine! I would never have imagined processing the input file twice

TIL what "fizzbuzz" is, thanks! Delete my comments since you've obviously seen them now.

Using any awk for a simple CSV as you show in your question, assuming your input isn't too massive to fit in memory:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR == 1 { print; next }
{
    for ( i=3; i<=4; i++ ) {
        max[$1,i] = ( length($i) > length(max[$1,i]) ? $i : max[$1,i] )
    }
    lines[NR] = $0
}
END {
    for ( nr=2; nr<=NR; nr++ ) {
        $0 = lines[nr]
        for ( i=3; i<=4; i++ ) {
            $i = max[$1,i]
        }
        print
    }
}


$ awk -f tst.awk file
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,HEADER4
ap3,799,474:::226:::5731,address 1:::address 9
afk,731,+636:::773:992,address 2
ppd,411,774:::+8825-22,address 6
ap3,799,474:::226:::5731,address 1:::address 9
ap3,799,474:::226:::5731,address 1:::address 9
ppd,411,774:::+8825-22,address 6

but if your real CSV is more complicated, e.g. can have quoted fields containing commas and/or newlines, then see What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk? for how to handle that.

You can alter ARGV and ARGC to read the input file in two passes. In the first pass, keep the longest 3rd and 4th column for each distinct value of the 1st column in two arrays, and in the second pass, replace the 3rd and 4th columns with the longest values in the arrays given the current 1st column for output:
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
    ARGV[2] = ARGV[1]
    ++ARGC
}
NR == FNR {
    if (length($3) > length(c3[$1]))
        c3[$1] = $3
    if (length($4) > length(c4[$1]))
        c4[$1] = $4
    next
}
FNR > 1 {
    $3 = c3[$1]
    $4 = c4[$1]
}
1

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/UniqueLoudQuery

there's a small chance this might mess up the header line if $1 can be its header value, and the data field is longer

Right. Added a FNR > 1 guard then. Thanks.

Thanks for your solution, it works correct. I would never have imagined processing the input file twice. A question not too much related. Can awk handle csv files (comma delimiter) that have some columns with a text with commas surrounded by double quotes? like a,b,"hdyd, jdjd" and sometimes the columns surrounded by double quotes can have line break. I see MS Excel can detect that, don't know awk or a another scripting tool. Thanks

@RasecMalkic Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642102/how-to-make-awk-ignore-the-field-delimiter-inside-double-quotes ?

@RasecMalkic if your real input has quoted fields containing newlines and/or commas and/or escaped quotes then you need to start showing examples like that in your questions as they require quite different solutions from the examples you are currently showing.

That's including the length of the $3 from the header line with the length of $3 from the data lines below it and so it'd fail if there just happened to be a line in the data that had $1 containing the same string as it has in the header line, HEADER1.

Hi Ed, thanks for your contribution. My original issue was remove repeated values from CSV file, I was trying to make equal some fields, after that remove duplicates. Real file has quoted fields, commas and new lines(like when we press Alt+enter to change line within same cell in Excel). I opened the csv file in Excel to be sure of the format and since I didn't know if awk could handle those cases, I selected only some columns that are not quoted to apply awk script on them. The modify only those columns and paste them in corresponding place inside Excel. A quite large process.
