AWK command not working as expected giving & data as output
I have file where I need to find if some column is empty. File is delimited by ;
Some of data contains & in word and awk is command  it not working for same .
lets say I have file( dedup_company_output.txt file name) which has following data :
"c1";"c2";"c3";"c4";"c5"
900;"DAVIES TURNER &AMP; CO LTD";;315235;1
909;"DAVIES TURNER CO LTD";;444;1
909;"DAVIES TURNER CO LTD";;;1

Now in first line I am not sure why we are getting & for &  and hence when I am running following command it is giving me incorrect result .
awk -F';' '$4 == ""' dedup_company_output.txt> result.txt

As as output I am getting

900;"DAVIES TURNER &AMP; CO LTD";;315235;1
909;"DAVIES TURNER CO LTD";;;1

where as I was expecting only

909;"DAVIES TURNER CO LTD";;;1

Do I need to change something in this command to include & as part of word or do I need to change file .

Not clear and crossposted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/787239/awk-command-not-working-as-expected-giving-data-as-output

The problem has nothing to do with &. The problem is that you have ; inside a field. -F';' doesn't know that these characters should not be treated as field separators.

This is because the & character is encoded as &AMP;. awk treats &AMP; as part of the string.
This should work
awk -F';' '{if ($4 == "" || $4 == "&AMP;") print $0}' dedup_company_output.txt > result.txt

By doing this, you first check for the empty fields, even if there is some unexpected encoding like &AMP;

Wouldn't it be better to define the field separator so it only recognizes ;s that aren't inside quotes? (GNU awk has an extension that allows this, though I don't recall the details off the top of my head).

@CharlesDuffy: Unfortunately, the --csv option in GNU awk only supports , as a CSV filed separator.

It's not --csv I was thinking of, actually. See FPAT, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642102/how-to-make-awk-ignore-the-field-delimiter-inside-double-quotes and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html (which has a "rewrite this now that --csv exists" note at the top, incidentally)

Once you get into quoted fields, consider using a CSV parser. You can use Ruby:
ruby -r csv -e '
opts={:col_sep=>";"}
f=File.open(ARGV[0])
f.drop(1).each{|line| 
    puts line if CSV.parse_line(line, **opts)[3]==nil
}
' file.csv

Prints:
909;"DAVIES TURNER CO LTD";;;1

(The GNU awk --csv option only supports , as a CSV separator unfortunately or you could use that.)
You could also use mlr:
mlr --csv --ifs ';' --ofs ';' filter '$c4==""' file.csv | sed 1d

# same

